# How to verify an email signature from Facebook?

Tags: encryption, digital-signature

Facebook allows users

> to add OpenPGP public keys to their profile; these keys can be used to "end-to-end" encrypt notification emails sent from Facebook to your preferred email accounts. – [Securing Email Communications from Facebook](https://de-de.facebook.com/notes/protect-the-graph/securing-email-communications-from-facebook/1611941762379302/)

Facebook provides a public key (0x2F3898CEDEE958CF) at https://www.facebook.com/facebook/publickey/download/

“encrypted notifications” regarding my account have been sent to me repeatedly via email from Facebook (noreply@facebookmail.com). These emails are encrypted with my public key, that I have uploaded to Facebook. These emails are signed with a key (0x3028CF59770E7A01) which is not the one provided by Facebook (0x2F3898CEDEE958CF). When I try to import the key 0x3028CF59770E7A01 with Enigmail the following notification is displayed:

> The key with ID 0x3028CF59770E7A01 is not available on the keyserver. Most likely, the owner of the key did not upload their key to the keyserver.
>
> Please ask the sender of the message to send you their key by email.

- I have found no way to contact the sender of the message.
- I have found no source for the key 0x3028CF59770E7A01.

My main question: How can I verify the email signature from Facebook?

And by the way: Why would Facebook use a key that produces a signature that can not be verified?

**Update**

Looking up the key 0x2F3898CEDEE958CF on a keyserver (see e.g. [keyserver.ubuntu.com](https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?search=0x2F3898CEDEE958CF&op=index)) will show a recent inclusion of a [subkey 0x3028CF59770E7A01](https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?search=0x3028CF59770E7A01&op=index):

```
sub rsa4096/3028cf59770e7a01 2019-07-08T16:09:07Z            
sig sbind 2f3898cedee958cf 2019-07-08T16:09:07Z ____________________ 2020-01-04T20:00:00Z []
```

This is in accordance with the information provided by Facebook in their post [Securing Email Communications from Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/notes/protecting-the-graph/securing-email-communications-from-facebook/1611941762379302)

> Facebook's OpenPGP key comprises a long term primary key with short term subkeys; this allows us to frequently rotate our operational keys whilst maintaining the web of trust and a consistent identity over time.

However this subkey apparently is not public and attempts to receive this missing key from a keyserver fail.

```
gpg: Signature made Di 06 Aug 2019 17:56:19 CEST
gpg:                using RSA key 3B6C6808FC9D75EDAE0184E73028CF59770E7A01
gpg: Can't check signature: No public key
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [facebook.asc](https://www.facebook.com/facebook/publickey/download/) provided by Facebook actually holds two subkeys, which can be seen by executing `gpg --show-key --with-colons facebook.asc`

```
pub:-:4096:1:2F3898CEDEE958CF:1431903600:1581038771::-:
uid:::::::::Facebook, Inc.:
sig:::1:2F3898CEDEE958CF:1517966771:::::[selfsig]::13x:
sub:-:4096:1:D2CC929B77D6D6F9:1547468530:1564686000:::
sig:::1:2F3898CEDEE958CF:1547468530:::::[keybind]::18x:
sub:-:4096:1:3028CF59770E7A01:1562602147:1578168000:::
sig:::1:2F3898CEDEE958CF:1562602147:::::[keybind]::18x:
```

Notice that the second subkey is the ominous 0x3028CF59770E7A01.

Importing this file to my keyring (`gpg --import facebook.asc` ) works and suddenly

```
gpg: Signature made Di 06 Aug 2019 18:00:09 CEST
gpg:                using RSA key 3B6C6808FC9D75EDAE0184E73028CF59770E7A01
gpg: Good signature from "Facebook, Inc." [unknown]
gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
Primary key fingerprint: 31A7 0953 D8D5 90BA 1FAB  3776 2F38 98CE DEE9 58CF
     Subkey fingerprint: 3B6C 6808 FC9D 75ED AE01  84E7 3028 CF59 770E 7A01
```

While Enigmail's Key Management repeatedly fails to download the subkey 0x3028CF59770E7A01 (e.g. from hkps://keys.openpgp.org or hkps://hkps.pool.sks-keyservers.net) it *is* possible to receive the subkey via `gpg --keyserver hkps://keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 0x3028CF59770E7A01`:

```
gpg: key 2F3898CEDEE958CF: 586 duplicate signatures removed
gpg: key 2F3898CEDEE958CF: 1417 signatures not checked due to missing keys
gpg: key 2F3898CEDEE958CF: 1 signature reordered
gpg: key 2F3898CEDEE958CF: public key "Facebook, Inc." imported
gpg: marginals needed: 3  completes needed: 1  trust model: pgp
gpg: depth: 0  valid:   2  signed:   0  trust: 0-, 0q, 0n, 0m, 0f, 2u
gpg: next trustdb check due at 2021-02-07
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
```

**Update** My default keyserver was stripping the user IDs from the keys, resulting in `new key but contains no user ID - skipped`. Using keyserver.ubuntu.com solves that. [This answer explains why](https://superuser.com/a/1485255).

Comment: Hi, is there a website or anything that lists the most recent key IDs?

Comment: I do not think so. But please pose you own question! Comments are not intended for asking questions. :-)

Comment: Can I ask why you are using sudo to import a key into your non-root user account?

Comment: [@Steve Beattie](https://superuser.com/users/1655585/steve-beattie) Not entirely sure as to why I did previously use `sudo gpg --import facebook.asc`, but `sudo gpg --recv-keys 0x3028CF59770E7A01` was my workaround regarding `new key but contains no user ID - skipped`. Setting a keyserver is obviously the right way to do this. I have updated my answer.